# Convert vector of indices into matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a vector of indices into a matrix with ones in the columns of the indices.

```
x = [2;1;3;1];
m = someFunc(x,3)
% m =
%
%   0   1   0
%   1   0   0
%   0   0   1
%   1   0   0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the values of multiple points in a matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850368/how-can-i-change-the-values-of-multiple-points-in-a-matrix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use SUB2IND function:

```
colN = 3;
assert(max(x)<=colN,'Not enough columns') %# check that you have enough columns
%# other checks that x is valid indices

m = zeros(numel(x),colN);
m(sub2ind(size(m),1:numel(x),x')) = 1;
```

Answer (score 15):

I tested the sub2ind function, but on the coursera Machine Learning forum I was pointed to this beauty.

```
m = eye(num_cols)(x,:);
```

It uses the identity matrix to select the appropriate column based on the value in x.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax for this

Comment: Play with it. Try with a small identity matrix and first run single values instead of a vector x. E.g. `eye(4)(3,:)` This will take the third row of the identity matrix. Then try with a vector `eye(4)([2,3,1], :)`. This will take the second, third and first row of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question, so I didn't want to open a new one. I wanted to convert a row vector of indices into a matrix with ones in the rows (instead of columns) of the indices. I could have used the previous answer and inverted it, but I thought this would perform better with very large matrices.

```
octave> x = [2 1 3 1];
octave> m = setRowsToOne(x, 3)
m =

   0   1   0   1
   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0
```

I couldn't see how to use sub2ind to accomplish this, so I calculated it myself.

```
function matrixResult = setRowsToOne(indexOfRows, minimumNumberOfRows)
   numRows = max([indexOfRows minimumNumberOfRows]);
   numCols = columns(indexOfRows);
   matrixResult = zeros(numRows, numCols);
   assert(indexOfRows > 0, 'Indices must be positive.');
   matrixResult(([0:numCols-1]) * numRows + indexOfRows) = 1;
end

x = [2 1 3 1];
m = setRowsToOne(x, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) which makes this very easy, like so:

```
accumarray([ (1:length(x))', x ], 1, [4, 3])
```

The `1:length(x)` part specifies into which rows the ones go, and `x` into which columns.