# Force the number of outputs from function call without setting output variables

Tags: matlab

For any function, I am able to dictate the variables to be returned by explicitly defining how many outputs I am expecting `[out1,out2,...,outn] = ...`

*Edit: Being able to maximize potential # of outputs would also be useful*

**Example problem**

The following code does exactly what is expected (yes, it is redundant with `myArray(IND) = 1;`)

```
[I,J] = ind2sub(size(myArray),IND)
myArray(I,J) = 1;
```

When I try to pass the function arguments directly, I don't get the results I wannt

```
myArray(ind2sub(size(myArray),IND)) = 1;
```

I effectively get `myArray(I) = 1;` when I wanted `myArray(I,J) = 1;`

**Question**

How can I dictate how many output variables are returned without explicitly defining my output arguments?

I expect some function in the `eval()` family or some typecasting `[],{},(:), etc.` will do the trick but I have not seen any documentation or gotten any of them to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate issue with using the output of `ind2sub` directly as an index into `myArray` without an intermediate variable is that only the first output of `ind2sub` is requested by `subsindex` when indexing into `myArray`. The first output is then used as a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to index into `myArray` and assign values which resulting in your unexpected behavior.

Instead, you can use a [cell array to capture as many outputs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-8) as you want and then rely on `{}` indexing to yield a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).

```
[outputs{1:ndims(myArray)}] = ind2sub(size(myArray), IND);
```

You can then use this cell array containing all outputs to then forward all values as [inputs or subscripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-13) elsewhere:

```
myArray(outputs{:}) = 1;
```

That being said, in the example that you've shown, you really don't need to do any of this as you can use the linear indices `IND` to index into `myArray` directly. **[In fact, using the output of `ind2sub` will likely give you the *incorrect* assignment as every permutation of the subscripts will be used when assigning values rather than the element-wise pairing of subscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850368/how-can-i-change-the-values-of-multiple-points-in-a-matrix)**.

```
myArray(IND) = 1;
```

In general, you can use this technique along with `nargout` to request all output arguments *if there is a non-variable number of outputs*.

```
[outputs{1:nargout('func')}] = func(inputs);
```

Comment: Ah thank you, you've highlighted why there is a need for explicit output definitions for builtin functions with variable outputs.  I was hoping for an in-line solution that allows explicit output definitions without variable assignment (i.e. `eval('foo(...),"nargout", 2')` ) but I have not seen any evidence that one exists

Comment: @BrendanFrick I'm confused. There is. it's `[outputs{1:2}] = thing`

Comment: Can you call that inline? `foo1([outputs{1:2}] = foo2(...))`

Comment: @BrendanFrick No you need the temporary variable. I see what you are referring to now

Comment: @BrendanFrick The better way to "chain" function calls like that would be to use a function handle to `foo2` and have `foo1` call that with the inputs and then use the explicit outputs internally

Comment: @BrendanFrick There is sometimes a wish to over "optimise" code by making everything inline, there is no real disadvantage to using two lines, if anything it increases readability. If you were insistent on 1 line you could always cheat with a semi-colon `[outputs{1:2}] = foo2(...); foo1(outputs{:})`

Comment: @Wolfie Not really an 'optimization' issue, more of a 'clean code' issue. In this instance the interior function is a very simple index mapping. The reason why I might prefer to use  `eval('ind2sub(...),"nargout", 2') )` is because it is easier to recognize as _mapping a 1D index to a 2D index_ than multiple lines and a temporary variable.

Comment: @BrendanFrick Did you read my entire answer? The outputs that you're forwarding the way that you are aren't going to yield the correct result. See the linked post

Comment: @Suever Yes thank you! I edited the question (it is still redundant with just indexing 2D-array with a linear index) but it now should be doing what is described. My original intent was to map [1 2 3 4 5 6] to [1 2 3; 4 5 6] and I've done that in an easier way that is irrelevant to the original post